# android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar not found (Android Studio)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-support-library

for round about 2 weeks from now, I receive an error message, whenever I try to preview an .xml design-file in my Android Studio Project. As I am relatively new to the whole topic I'd like to ask whether you have an answer.

**The error message:**
 *Rendering Problems:

 The following classes could not be found:

- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar*

**OR**

*Rendering Problems:

 The following classes could not be found:

- android.support.v7.widget.CardView*

**One of the .xml files:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_tabs"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="VPlan App RC1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh"
                android:id="@+id/ic_refresh"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/primaryColor"
            android:textColorPrimary="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Also as it might help, here's the build.gradle file where the support library is located.

**The build.grade file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.nocomment.vplanehs'
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 16
        versionName '0.8.5_RC1'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.9'
}
```

In this project we also use volley as well as libraries from ZXing's QR Code reader.
I'd be very thankful if someone could help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try previewing with the *m* release in Android studio

Comment: The error/bug is in Android Studio I believe. Try as suggested by @UditMukherjee. I got these kind of error on the rendering screen when I first used code for Navigation Drawer.

Comment: Yup, the workaraound with the M preview was successful! Thanks!